Using different types of adverbs
Adverbs of  indefinite frequency time are put before the verb.


I always help her (good)
I help always her (wrong)


What about adverbs of time ending with "ly"? Do they normally go after the verb?

We meet daily to talk
vs
we daily meet to talk


Marta, a side note: in contexts like here at ELU it is very useful to distinguish between using  a term, phrase, etc. and mentioning it.  In English, the most common way to communicate that distinction is by using italics. Thus, London is the largest city in the UK, while London is a six-letter noun. You can learn more by consulting the article about this “use-mention distinction” at Wikipedia.

To do that here on StackExchange, one encloses text in asterisks. Thus, if you type *potato*, it gets displayed as potato.

That would be correct when you are discussing I always help her and I help always her.

After the verb (and any dependent objects) is a good choice for "daily".  "We meet daily" not "We daily meet", but both forms are understandable and have some use.
"Every day" is a more common adverb with this meaning and the same placing. "We meet every day" and not "#We every day meet"
"Daily" is often an adjective "Our daily meetings"

Would you accept "we daily meet to talk"?

After the verb (and any dependent objects) is a good choice for "daily".

If you know that after the verb is "right", what is the problem to solve?

Can it be before like my example?

See my answer; first paragraph.  Note my comment.  You know it should go after.  That is Good English.  Why do you care about whether you can speak badly?  If you put it before that is not the "good choice".  It is understandable, It has some use, but it is not good.
